# "SELECT DISTINCT field_name from table" Django using raw sql

Tags: django, django-orm

How can I run **`SELECT DISTINCT field_name from table;`** SQL query in Django as `raw sql` ?

When I try to use `Table.objects.raw("""SELECT DISTINCT field_name from table""")`, I got an exception as

> InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the model instances (which are useless if you want a single field), you can as well just use a plain db-api cursor:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select distinct field from table")
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0])
```

But for your example use case you don't need SQL at all - the orm has `values` and `values_list` querysets and a `distinct()` modifier too:

```
queryset = YourModel.objects.values_list("field", flat=True).order_by("field").distinct()
print(str(queryset.query))
# > 'SELECT DISTINCT `table`.`field` FROM `table` ORDER BY `table`.`title` ASC'
for title in queryset:
    print(title)
```

NB :

1/ since we want  single field, I use the `flat=True` argument to avoid getting a list of tuples

2/ I explicitely set the ordering on the field else the default ordering eventually defined in the model's meta could force the ordering field to be part of te generated query too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use some workaround

```
select field_name, max(id)
from table_name
group by field_name;
```

Comment: got same exception, `InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key`

Comment: @JPG Which primary key you have in your `Table` model?

Comment: The problem is in the `select` command. We should ad `id` (you were added `max('id')` not `id`)