# Django find all rows matching 2 columns criteria

Tags: django

Imagine the model Event like this

| name | email |
| --- | --- |
| A | u1@example.org |
| B | u1@example.org |
| B | u1@example.org |
| C | u2@example.org |
| B | u3@example.org |
| B | u3@example.org |
| A | u4@example.org |
| B | u4@example.org |

I would like to find all emails that contain name `A` and `B`. In my example `["u1@example.org", "u4@example.org"]`

Today I'm doing

```py
emails = [
    e["email"]
    for e in models.Event.objects.filter(name__in=["A", "B"])
    .values("email")
    .annotate(count=Count("id"))
    .order_by()
    .filter(count__gt=1)
]
```

It's not working because I'm also getting duplicates of emails containing only one name (like `u3@example.org`).

Answer (score 1):

After trying different approach, I found the solution

```py
events = ["A", "B"]
emails = [
    e["email"]
    for e in models.Event.objects.filter(name__in=events)
    .values("email")
    .annotate(count_name=Count("name", distinct=True))
    .order_by()
    .filter(count_name=len(events))
]
```

I need to group by `email` and count number of distinct `name` and filter by count equals to my number of events.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the model, there is this [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326971/select-distinct-field-name-from-table-django-using-raw-sql/52328021#52328021), that yields the expected result:

```
from django.db import connection

def get_random_events(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT email FROM event WHERE name = 'A' OR 'B'")
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0])

    return  render(request, 'blank.html')
```

As for the ORM the problem is the last part of the query, it does not seem possible to properly build the WHERE clause. My best attempt was using [Q lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), still...the same problem:

```
RandomEvent.objects.values('email').distinct().filter(Q(name='B') | Q(name='A'))

# Query Structure
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM random_event WHERE (name = 'B' OR name = 'A')
```